# google marker inbound not working with proper results

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have used google maps v3 and markerwithlabel as

js:

```
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
             position: latlng,
             map: map,
             title: p[2],
             labelText: '<div class="roundrect_apt">'+j+'</div><div class="line_apt"></div><div class="downline_apt"></div>',

             labelStyle: {top: "0px",  opacity: 0.75},
             labelVisible: true,
             infowindow:newinfowindow
        });
```

style:

```
    .roundrect_apt{
        width:28px;
        height:28px;
        border-radius:5px;
        background:#06F;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #666;
        border:3px solid #009;
        text-align: center; 
        color:#fff
        }

    .line_apt
    { width:5px; 
height:15px; 
background:linear-gradient(to right,grey,white); 
    moz-linear-gradient(right,grey,white); 
-o-linear-gradient(right,grey,white);
     webkit-linear-gradient(left,grey,white); 
margin-left:14px;
    }
    .downline_apt{ 
    width:18px; 
height:5px;
 background:#06F; 
border-top-left-radius:4px;
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 margin-left:7px;
box-shadow:1px 1px 1px #666; 
    }
```

and drawn a drag-gable circle. I am trying to show marker in that circle bound which working improperly.
Markers are shown even if they are out of bounds.

please help

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for your code? Also correct the syntax of styles.

Comment: What circle?  How are you testing for marker inside the circle?  If you are using the bounds of the circle, that doesn't mean the marker is inside the circle (bounds for a circle is a square)

Comment: circle.getBounds(); and cbounds.contains(latlng)
what should i use instead of bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must calculate the distance between the marker and the center of the circle. When it's not larger than the radius of the circle...draw the marker.

You may calculate the distance by using [`google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical)

Note: the geometry-library will not be loaded by default, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries

Comment: there is no function like circle.getBounds() in v3
k i'll check it thanks for reply

Comment: There is such a method, but I did not mention it, furthermore it will return a rectangle, which is not sufficient here(see the comment by geocodezip).